# How to apply plt.xticks for all the subplots?

Tags: pandas, seaborn, data-visualization

I am trying to do some simple visualizations using seaborn.

```
def show_figures():
  sns.barplot(ax=axes[0, 0], x=df['Genre'], y=df['NA_Sales'])
  sns.barplot(ax=axes[0, 1], x=df['Genre'], y=df['EU_Sales'])
  sns.barplot(ax=axes[1, 0], x=df['Genre'], y=df['JP_Sales'])
  sns.barplot(ax=axes[1, 1], x=df['Genre'], y=df['Other_Sales'])
show_figures()
plt.xticks(rotation=70)
plt.show()
```

I wanted to rotate the xticks of axes[1, 0] too, but I got this:

[image]

How can we rotate the xticks of all subplots ?

Thank you!

Comment: You have an iterable of `ax` in `axes` so you can do: `_ = [tick.set_rotation(70) for ax in axes.flat for tick in ax.get_xticklabels()]`. Though I think you maybe better off using a [`sns.catplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html) but this may require re-shaping your dataframe.

Comment: `for ax in axes.flat:
    for tick in ax.get_xticklabels():
      tick.set_rotation(70)` it solved the problem, Thank you !

Comment: Use `ax.tick_params(labelrotation=70)` to avoid the inner loop.